# Vuejs component with html attribute

Tags: vue.js

I am using single file components and I am wondering if something like this is possible:

```
<my-component param1='comp1'></my-component>
<my-component param1='comp2'></my-component>
<my-component param1='comp3'></my-component>
```

So when later methods for component `my-component` are called, each component can read param1 attribute. Is this possible with vuejs?

Just to clarify things little bit more:

I am writing component for table pagination - everything is cool, except for the case when there are several tables on the same page. In that case I would also need several pagination components. So I need a method which will connect table and pagination component through table id.

Something like this:

```
<table id="tbl1"></table>
<pagination-comp tblid="tbl1"></pagination-comp>

<table id="tbl2"></table>
<pagination-comp tblid="tbl2"></pagination-comp>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MattU - sorry, I've clarified further why I need this.

Comment: Is this not just a prop?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exactly what props did. Please follow [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) guide.